# Хранение данных полученных с сайта

Tags: android

Есть порядка 15-20 json файлов. Через Retrofit получаю эти данные в коллекции и вывожу в RecyclerView в различных фрагментах и активити. У меня такой вопрос. Как лучше организовать хранение и отображение этих данных?

Вот я получил парсингом json данные и загнал их в коллекции (получаю данные сразу не со всех 15-20 json файлов, а какого-нибудь одного в зависимости от того какое активити или фрагмент открывается). Как дальше лучше организовать вывод и хранение?

Или можно каждый раз при открытии актвиити/фрагмента получать данные из json? Прошу заметить я не прошу писать какой-то код, а лишь спрашиваю про процесс организации хранения и вывода данных

Comment: Можете сохранять в БД. Например с помощью [Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/index.html). А данные все статичные у вас или могут меняться? Для чего сохранять хотите?

Comment: Данные могут меняться

Answer (score 1):

Как правило делают так, получаете данные с сервера, сохраняете в БД и от туда достаете и показываете в ресайклере. Такой подход обеспечит "кеширование", то есть при старте приложения выводите данные из БД, а не идете на сервак за ними, тем самым пользователь намного раньше увидит инфу. Параллельно (в другом потоке) идете на сервак и проверяете актуальность данных, если надо, снова пишите в БД и показываете в списке.

Comment: Аа понял. Спасибо.